# Regex: how to extract function parameters

Tags: regex

I could not find similar question with what I am trying to get at.

I have a function:

```
Foo(int n, str b, Bar1(), Bar2(smth));
```

I am trying to write regex to get the following matches:

```
int n
str b
Bar()
Bar2(smth) // don't need recursion
```

I've managed to do it in 2 separate regexes:

```
(?<=\().*(?=\))
```

to get:

```
int n, str b, Bar1(), Bar2(smth)
```

then on that string, I 've used:

```
[^,\s*][a-zA-Z\s<>.()0-9]*
```

to get:

```
int n
str b
Bar()
Bar2(smth)
```

But I would really like to do it in a single regex statement, is it possible to somehow capture first regex in a group and then run second regex on that group in a single statement? I am still quite vague on using groups.

Comment: Please mention the tool/lang you're using.

Answer (score 1):

For the function call you happened to post, the following regex seems to work:

```
(?:\w+ \w+|\w+\(\w*\))
```

This pattern matches, alternatively, a type followed by variable name, or a function name, with optional parameters.  Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IAep1Z/1).

Comment: I am looking for something more generic sadly, it could be something like Foo(out int n)

Comment: ...then you asked the wrong question.  Update your question with the generic problem.  Most likely, you will need to write/use a _parser_ here; regex alone won't help.

Comment: yeah it's difficult to explain specific use case, as I am trying to parse any C# function basically... either function call or function definition, just trying to extract everything that is separated by commas inside (,,,,)

Comment: another example would be `public void Function(something here)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|\()\K\w+(?:\s+\w+|\s*\([^()]*\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OZZi09/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|\()` - either the end of the preceding match and then a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces, or a `(` char
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:\s+\w+|\s*\([^()]*\))` - a non-capturing group matching one of two alternatives

  - `\s+\w+` - one or more whitespaces and then one or more word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `\([^()]*\)` - a `(` char, then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
((?<=\(|,\s)((\w+\s)+\w+)|(\w+\((\w+(\,\s){0,1})*\)))
```

Check demo https://regex101.com/r/Bv1Y5L/1